# What are the twin "air data booms" on the Su-22?

Tags: feature-identification, su-17

The Su-22 has two protruding "probes" at the nose. What are they? [Air data probes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_data_boom) (why two?)? Antennas?

[image]
https://www.airliners.net/photo/Libya---Air/Sukhoi-Su-22M3/1615286/L

Comment: Thats a really good question, wikipedia seems to think that these are twin pitot coupled with AoA sensor tubes.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-17#Variants The shape of the tips is definitly pitot-tube like, and the fins would fit to sensing the angles of the incoming airflow...

Comment: Just for completeness: The original-language Su-22 technical manuals are available for download here (~15$/book): http://www.aircraft-reports.com/sukhoi-su-22-aircraft-technical-description-manual-exploatation-manual-book-9-equipment-part-1-service-russian-language/